# Solving a simple classical Hamiltonian problem

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, textbook-erratum

Suppose you've been given this Hamiltonian: $H = m\ddot{x}$ and are asked to find the equations of motion. (This is a simplified version of a question given [here](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/15584/1/How%20to%20Teach%20Quantum%20Mechanics%20%28David%20Albert%29%20Corrected%202.pdf) on page 3.)

This isn't a homework problem; I'm trying to learn Hamiltonian mechanics on my own "for fun." I'm having a hard time finding examples online to help me understand how to solve such problems, but I'll show you what I've tried.

$$-\dot{p} = \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial q}$$
$$\dot{q} = \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial p}$$

So first let's try to find $\dot{q}$. We can rewrite $H = m\ddot{x} = \dot{p}$, and now we have to find the derivative of $\dot{p} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}$ with respect to $p$. I'm not sure how to think about that.

I'm told that the answer is $x(t) = c_0 + c_1t$. Working backward, this gives us $\dot{q}=c_1$.  But if $\dot{q} = \frac{\partial{H}}{\partial p} = c_1$ and $H = \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}$, then apparently we should have found that $\frac{\partial}{\partial p} \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = c_1$. I'm not sure why we would have assumed such a thing (or if it even makes sense).

Trying the other equation first didn't lead anywhere better.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding some things here, and any guidance would be appreciated.

References:

1. David Albert, *HOW TO TEACH QUANTUM MECHANICS,* notes; p. 3 eq. (1).

Comment: Why does your Hamiltonian has units of force?

Comment: I think your Hamiltonian is unphysical.

Comment: The Hamiltonian in the linked document is unphysical!!  He says it consists of kinetic energy terms.  Does that look like kinetic energy?  (answer: no, it doesn't)  I think he made a typo.  More accurately, a brain fart.  Look at the text following eq (3).

Comment: @garyp Wow, okay. I suppose maybe Prof. Albert meant to write that $H=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2$, which is a particle with KE but no PE, so has no forces acting on it? (Edit: thanks for pointing out eq 3; this does seem to be what he meant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sentence below eq. (3) it becomes clear that there is a typo in eq. (1). It was intended to read 
$$ H~=~\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2_1+ \dot{x}^2_2). \tag{1'}$$
Even this is slightly wrong because the [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) is [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) a function of momenta rather than velocity, so it should read 
$$ H~=~\frac{1}{2m}(p^2_1+ p^2_2). \tag{1"}$$
This brings us back to OP's question: A Hamiltonian does by definition not contain any dots, let alone double dots.